# How do I fix this problem in Eclipse (Ubuntu)?

Tags: c++, eclipse

In c++, it says semantic errors on cout / 'symbol cout cannot be resolved' and unresolved inclusions (#include),  and I already installed C/C++ Development SDK as per tutorials. I wonder what else  to do.

I also tried following tutorials online yet to no avail. As of now, I am still looking for solutions online.

Comment: There is no symbol cout in C.

Answer (score 1):

you try use this function if you are using c

```
printf();
```

c language has no cout object

and if you are using c++ then try add

```
using namespace std;
```

at top of file after include statements
or use

```
std::cout
```